# Trying to achieve a Predis sortby

Tags: php, sorting, redis, predis

i'm trying to make a sort by hash value of string field with predis.

The official doc says i am to use : sort($key[, array $options])

Now my hash structure looks like this :

```
$key1 = 'Let It Bleed';
$redis->hmset($key1, [
    'year' => 1969,
    'price' => 18.70,
    'id_artist' => 'art_1'
    ]);
```

And i want to sort all the keys by 'year'. I tried :

```
$allKeys = $redis->keys('*');

    sort($allKeys, ['year']);
```

But i get this error : Warning: sort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\redislol\lol.php on line 72

Is it possible to sort with this function or do i have to try something more elaborate ?